# SHELL/AppleScript: On "Cancel" stop AppleScript and Quit Shell

Tags: macos, shell, applescript

I am simply trying to stop/exit the script after the user hits "Cancel" butoon.

```
osascript -e 'display dialog "" buttons {"Cancel","Continue"} default button 1 Cancel button 1 with icon stop
set xxxx to button returned of the result
if xxxx is "Cancel" then
    error number -128
end if'
```

Although it continues executing the remaining Shell script. I have also tried `do shell script "exit"`, `return` and redefining the cancel button in various ways.

Any advice would be much appreciated

Comment: What remaining shell script?  Note that each `osascript` runs in its own environment, so the dialog will just cancel that script - you will need to handle the _result_ from the particular script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be what's required :

```
osascript -e 'display dialog "" buttons {"Cancel","Continue"} default button 1 Cancel button 1 with icon stop
set xxxx to button returned of the result
if xxxx is "Cancel" then
    error number -128
end if' || exit
```

Comment: That was it! I feel ashamed, that I didn't know I could combine `&& || ` with `osascript`! Many thanks!